# Hacking bad people to help a good cause

Tags: random

I want to hire a hacker to get emails by and between 2 people I think are participating in something unethical.  It is very important that I not break any laws.  A review of this site makes it appear "hacking" someone's email is illegal.  Please confirm/dispute.  This case involves a defensless child.  I really need help but I need to get the information the right way.  Subpoenas produced nothing.  Any ideas are welcome

Comment: I don't know how you got that impression, but accessed someone's email account is not legal (in basically every country). If you believe these people are involved in criminal actions, then go file charges at the responsible government institution in your country.

Comment: Btw even if you would actually do that, how would that help anybody?

Answer (score 3):

It is not legal to access somebody's email account, no matter for what reason. If you have evidence that proof these people commited a crime, then file charges against them.

Only law enforcement would be allowed to do so and only if a judge sees enough proof that it would be neccessary to do so. They would then contact the email provider, who should then give them access to the required data.

Comment: "It is not legal to access somebody's email account, no matter for what reason." AFAIK some governments found enough reason...

Comment: Natural Person != Government Agency or Law Enforcement. While I agree that mass surveillance, even when legitimated by law, is unethical, this does not legitimate vigilantism.